# How to write Mongo Aggregation to sort by element inside array

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

Here is the example:

```
{_id: 111, sort: [{order:1}, {order:3}]}
{_id: 222, sort: [{order:2}, {order:5}]}
{_id: 333, sort: [{order:1}, {order:3}, {order:4}]}
```

I want to sort by sort.order from big to small, and get

```
{_id: 222, sort: {order:5}}
{_id: 333, sort: {order:4}}
{_id: 111, sort: {order:3}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) them to determine which one has highest value and then group back to take only one:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$sort" },
    { $sort: { "sort.order": -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id",
            sort: { $first: "$sort" }
        }
    },
    { $sort: { "sort.order": -1 } },
])
```